# Can anyone help to fecth only dictionary format data from a file(example of data shown below)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Here is the how the file is setup:

```
Some lines written here.

Line one written here.

line two written here.

key1:value1

key2:value2

key3:value3

key4:value4
```

All above keys and values are mentioned. Then:

```
Line three written here.

key5:value5   key6:value6

key7:value7
```

I have tried this way but did not get the desired result..

with open(r'/home/rajat/PycharmProjects/MyProject/testfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

regex = re.compile(r'''
    [\S]+:
    (?:
    \s
    (?!\S+:)\S+
    )+
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

matches = regex.findall(str(lines))

for match in matches:
    print(match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finally I got it what i wanted by myself...

## Exact code below for my solution.

```
import re

with open(r'/home/coding_learner/PycharmProjects/MyProject/testfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = map(lambda s: s.strip(), lines)

r = re.compile(".[\S]+: [\S]+")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, lines))
print(newlist)
```